# Add a "Build and Analyze" button to XCode's toolbar

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

Is there a way to add a "Build & Analyze" icon to XCode's toolbar? If not, is there at least a way to assign a keyboard shortcut to this option?

Comment: Just in case you find this helpful, you can also get Xcode to automatically run the analyzer with each build. Just edit your target build settings and set "Run Static Analyzer" to true. Or, if you are using xcconfig files, set RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER = YES

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like no on the toolbar item.  To see the customization options for a toolbar control-click it (or right click it if you have a two button mouse).

You can assign a keyboard shortcut to any menu item in Mac OS X via System Preferences.  See http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/8564.html

Xcode also has its own keybindings interface, which you can find in Xcode preferences.

Comment: Actually, on my machine it's already bound to cmd-shift-A.  I don't recall adding that, so perhaps it's default?